# Difference operation on Boolean modifier not showing once applied

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, 3d-printing

I have checked normals and removed doubles but still cannot get the Difference operation on Boolean modifier to work properly. The choker object is hollow, however I expected the modifier would still function using these two meshes. My aim is to cut a hole at the end of the choker. I am able to use the modifier using other basic shapes in a new file. How can I correct this problem? The choker object is hollow to save on material costs when used for 3D printing.   [image]

[image]

Comment: Another option you can try is Knife Project

Answer (score 1):

The simplest definition of `Boolean` with the `Difference` operation is that it eliminates the common region that is occupied by 2 geometries. 
[image]

In your project, You may notice that both the geometries share a common region.
[image: Common region]

You added the modifier to the `Cylinder` with `Choker` as the target object.
Ultimately the some the `Cylinder` part will get removed as the modifier is for the `Cylinder`, not for the `Choker`. But you want a hole in the `Choker`.So the best solution is to add the `Boolean` modifier to the `Choker`, with `Difference` as the operation, and the target object as the `Cylinder`.

However there will still be some portion remaining in the bottom.
[image: The bottom half is not solved.]

So you have to apply the modifier and delete it in `Edit Mode`. But you may have to apply the first 2 modifiers to get the desired result.
[image: So this is the final result]

Hope this helped!